# Mouse coordinate based perspective rotation with centered div [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, perspective

Second question I've asked, so if I need to add anything else, let me know please!

Been looking everywhere to try and understand concepts, but I feel like I am over thinking it. What I am trying to do is base "transform: rotateX("x"deg)" off of the x location of the users cursor proportionately from the size of the window. Here is a gif that does what I want, but they use matrix3D instead of just transform's rotate.

http://i.imgur.com/tUZSLXA.gif

Here is a js fiddle of what I have so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/z7bet2sw/

JS:

```
function rotate() {
    var x = event.clientX;

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var midpoint = w / 2;

    // restrictions for rotation
    if (x > -20 && x < 20) {


        document.getElementsById("logo").style.transform = "perspective(550px)" + "rotateY(" + x + "deg)";
    } else {

    }
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", rotate);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the event parameter to `rotate` function from `addEventListener`, and also you need to calculate a relative position from the x coordinates to get a value between -20 and 20:

```
function rotate (event) 
{
    var x = event.clientX;
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var midpoint = w / 2;
    var pos = x - midpoint;
    var val = (pos / midpoint) * 20;
    var logo = document.getElementById ("logo");
    logo.style.transform = "perspective(550px) rotateY(" + val + "deg)";
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event)
{
    rotate(event)
}, false);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/dwvhkrcr/)

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- you are using `document.getElementsById` which should actually be `document.getElementById` (no `s`)
- you should subtract `midpoint` from `x`

Updated code:

```
function rotate() {
  var x = event.clientX;

  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var midpoint = w / 2;

  x -= midpoint;
  if (x > -20 && x < 20) {
    document.getElementById("logo").style.transform = "perspective(550px)" + "rotateY(" + x + "deg)";
  } else {

  }
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jacquesc/z7bet2sw/1/

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Is there a way to make it so it uses the entirety of the width of the window and not just ~40 pixels worth?

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that you just need to change the bounds on the test on the values of `x`...